# dont work print linked list, node multidata

Tags: java, linked-list

each node has three data and a pointer, when printing only the current node is displayed.

```
package lista.enlazada1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaEnlazada1 {

public String marca;
public String modelo;
public int kilometraje;
public ListaEnlazada1 nodosiguiente;


public static void main(String[] args) {
/* enter the number of nodes to be created */
Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar)");
int n,contador=0;
n=leer.nextInt();

/* the three data of the node is entered */
for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
   ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();
    System.out.print("ingrese la marca ");
      nodo.marca=leer.next();
      System.out.print("ingrese el modelo ");
      nodo.modelo=leer.next();
      System.out.print("ingrese el kilometraje ");
      nodo.kilometraje=leer.nextInt();

/* the node is created  */  

 if(contador==0){
 nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
 contador ++;
 } else {
 nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
 contador ++;
 }    

/* nodes are printed  */
for ( i =1; i <= n; i++){
System.out.println("marca " +nodo.marca+ "\n");
    System.out.println("modelo " +nodo.modelo+ "\n");
    System.out.println("kilometraje " +nodo.kilometraje+ "\n");
    System.out.println("apuntador " +nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");    

}

}

}

}
```

as an autoincremental variable is created, example the variable is called node, then it is incremented and called node1.

I must create an autoincremental variable to be able to print all the nodes.

Comment: Your code as formatted is very difficult to read. Please consider editing your post and fixing your indentation style so that it is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (site software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a bunch of things in your code:

1: You had a nested for loop; I reassembled that to 2 for loops: one to read the data of new nodes, and another to print the data.

2: When using Linked lists, you must use an auxiliar List, by maintaining the header to use the list again.

3: In the printing for loop, finished a cycle, you must get the next node.

Here it is:

```
package lista.enlazada1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaEnlazada1 {

    public String marca;
    public String modelo;
    public int kilometraje;
    public ListaEnlazada1 nodosiguiente;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* enter the number of nodes to be created */
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar)");
        int n,contador=0;
        n=leer.nextInt();

        // Create a node to keep the header, and an auxiliar
        // to traverse the list
        ListaEnlazada1 cab = null, aux = null;

        /* the three data of the node is entered */
        for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
            ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();
            System.out.print("ingrese la marca ");
            nodo.marca=leer.next();
            System.out.print("ingrese el modelo ");
            nodo.modelo=leer.next();
            System.out.print("ingrese el kilometraje ");
            nodo.kilometraje=leer.nextInt();

            /* the node is created  */  

            if(contador==0)
                cab = aux = nodo;
            else {
                aux.nodosiguiente = nodo;
                aux = aux.nodosiguiente;
            }
            contador++;
        }

        /* nodes are printed */
        for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
        // When using "println", automatically jumps a line
        // after printing, so there's no need to write "\n"
        // unless you want to jump a line twice
            System.out.println("marca " +cab.marca); 
            System.out.println("modelo " +cab.modelo);
            System.out.println("kilometraje " +cab.kilometraje);
            System.out.println("apuntador " +cab.nodosiguiente + "\n");
            cab = cab.nodosiguiente; // Here we get the next node
        }
    }
}
```

As said in the comments, it is a very good practice to keep your code well indented to make it easy to read. Good luck!